# PowerShell - OR operator

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run this command to get both A and CNAME records, but it just doesn't seem to work, my syntax is wrong. It only retrieves DNS records of type CNAME.

The actual command is:
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -RRType "CNAME"

```
$results = Get-DnsServerZone | % {
$zone = $_.zonename
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $zone -filter {(RRType -like "CNAME") -or (RRType -like "A")}   | select @{n='ZoneName';e={$zone}}, HostName, RecordType, @{n='RecordData';e={if ($_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString) {$_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString} else {$_.RecordData.NameServer.ToUpper()}}}
}

$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\DNSRecords10.csv -Append
```

Comment: `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` doesn't have a `-Filter` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Where-Object` to filter since the cmdlet doesn't have a parameter of its own:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone |
    Where-Object { $_.RRType -in 'CNAME', 'A' } |
    Select-Object -Property @(
        @{ Name       = 'ZoneName'
           Expression = { $zone }
         }
        'HostName'
        'RecordType'
        @{ Name       = 'RecordData'
           Expression = {
                if ($_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString) {
                    $_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString
                } else {
                    $_.RecordData.NameServer.ToUpper()
                }
            }
         }
    )
```

As a footnote, `-like` is the same as using `-eq` if you're not using wildcards.

---

Documentation:

- [`Get-DnsServerResourceRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/get-dnsserverresourcerecord?view=win10-ps)
- [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Thank you, but how would I export the results of this to a CSV?

Comment: @Aziz Just add `| Export-Csv -Path .\myfile.csv -NoTypeInformation` to the end of the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [the solution proposed by TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50820930/712649) is to simply issue two queries:

```
@(
  Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $zone -RRType CNAME
  Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $zone -RRType A
) | select @{n='ZoneName';e={$zone}}, HostName, RecordType, @{n='RecordData';e={if ($_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString) {$_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString} else {$_.RecordData.NameServer.ToUpper()}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run it but I get:

    At line:2 char:50+   Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $zone -RRType CNAME
+                                                  ~
    Missing closing ')' in expression.
    At line:3 char:3
    +   Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $zone -RRType A
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token 'Get-DnsServerResourceRecord' in expression or statement.
    At line:4 char:1
    + ) | select @{n='ZoneName';e={$zone}}, HostName, RecordType, 
    @{n='RecordData';e={ ...